# MD5 encrypt selected GDrive files

Tags: md5, gdrive

not being a coder myself but need to know for a task of an AppSheet app project, if it basically is possible to MD5 or other encrypt actual GDoc, GSheet, image, etc. files.
So if someone logs into that given Gdrive, they would not be able to open the documents, without decryption.

Thx
Frank

Comment: MD5 is a *hash* function, not an encryption algorithm. Typically hashing something is irreversible. Also, MD5 is no longer considered secure.

Comment: Ok thank you for clarification. Is there a way to encrypt GDrive files or their content ?

Comment: By GDrive you mean Google Drive? Google Drive automatically encrypts things for you. The only problem would be someone obtaining access to your account which then they can see your files. As far as I know you would have to use an encryption system and copy-paste the ciphertext yourself (make sure to keep the key and the encryption algorithm type, if you lose them you can't decrypt it!)

Comment: ok, so users who login to the same Google-Drive account can only make use of encrypted files, where they are shared the decryption-key.

In fact I have this task, to secure stuff in an otherway shared Google-Drive account.

How would I go about it ? Is this a script I can use or need to create for G-Drive ?

Comment: Google drive encrypts the files when it is stored on their server. It then decrypts them when you view them. To encrypt them yourself you would have to run the content of the files through some sort of encryption program (like bitlocker).